# Use Eclipse/CMake with existing C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, cmake, qt-creator, eclipse-cdt

I have been using `Qt Creator` as an IDE for some C++ project (non-QT) and I love it. Recently I have been thinking to try out `Eclipse` mainly for learning a new tool and also the fact that I'm not a big fan of the debugger mode in `Qt Creator`!

Anyhow, I figured I could potentially use the makefile generated by the qmake, but though hey let's also learn `CMake`! So, I was wondering if someone could point me to some nice tutorials on this (I have not had much luck myself)?  Specifically, I like to have the ability to create and maintain `CMakeList.txt` files and build/run the project directly within Eclipse ... just as you would by editing a `.pro` file inside Qt Creator.

Thanks

Comment: Two things : 1. Qt Creator knows cmake and you don't eclipse. 2. cmake has a good tutorial in it's official site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake includes an Eclipse CDT4 generator since version 2.6; you should probably take a look at [this page](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake%3aEclipse_UNIX_Tutorial), it explains three different possibilities for using Eclipse and CMake together. From my personal experience, solution 1 works pretty well in Unix environments.